# Apache substitute module to replace the host url

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to replace url(http:\/\/test.com\/) inside a script with (https:\/\/test1.com\/).

Could someone give me the substitute rule to identify and replace the url

Answer (score 1):

What is unclear from the example in the [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_substitute.html)?

```
<Location />
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute s/foo/bar/ni
</Location>
```

> **`i`**   Perform a case-insensitive match.
>   **`n`** By default the pattern is treated as a regular expression. Using the n flag forces the pattern to be treated as a fixed string.
>
> If either the pattern (`foo`) or the substitution (`bar`) contain a
>   slash <kbd>/</kbd> character then an alternative delimiter should be
>   used (such as <kbd>|</kbd> )